# Update apiserver certificates for HA k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have HA k8s cluster that was created by kubeadm. I would like to update API server certificate to add additional SANs. For this purpose I followed some steps described in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360361/invalid-x509-certificate-for-kubernetes-master), but what I did for HA cluster:

- Removed API server certificates *on all control-plane nodes*
- Retrieved current kubeadm configmap

> ```
> kubectl get configmap kubeadm-config \
>   --namespace kube-system \
>   --output jsonpath={{ .data.ClusterConfiguration }}
> ```

- Extended it with necessary configuration part

> ```
> apiServer:
>   certSANs:
>     - localhost
>     - 127.0.0.1
> ```

- Generated new certificates with updated configuration *on all control-plane nodes*

> `kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --config <config_path>`

- Restarted API server container *on all control-plane nodes*
- Updated in-cluster configuration

> `kubeadm init phase upload-config kubeadm --config <config_path>`

The question is if these steps are correct or there is another way that is more simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way I come up with is this:

```
# remove current apiserver certificates
sudo rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*

# generate new certificates
sudo kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Remember that you need to run it on all control-plain nodes.